# Adding an extra field to serializers.ModelSerializer

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer which does its job:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
class FavoriteRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%b %d, %y')
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteRecord
        fields = ['user', 'date', 'record']
```

For some reason, I want the serializer to add an extra field, something like `is_favorite = True` when I serialize a `FavoriteRecord` object. So, the resulting serialized object could look something like this:

```js
{ user: 1,
  date: April 28, 21,
  record: 3,
  is_favorite: true //this extra field is what I want 
}
```

Is it possible? (I know it can be done from the view, but I am not allowed to change the view- all I can change is this serializer.)

Comment: That is the ***`is_favorite: true`*** will be a constant? \

Comment: Depends- for example I might want to read another field to infer the value. But it will always be a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` it's value is dynamically evaluated by the serializer itself and not the model. Using this method the value can be generated in the context of the current session.

```
class FavoriteRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%b %d, %y')
    is_favorite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteRecord
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_is_favorite(self, instance):
        return True
```

Any `SerializerMethodField` will look for a `get_<field_name>` method and use it as source.